# Fix sag in soffit (faux ceiling) for duct work

Tags: drywall, ceiling, ducts, patching-drywall, patch

We have a faux ceiling that houses duct work.  The faux ceiling wraps around the interior of the house to hide duct work that otherwise cannot go in the original ceiling.  I don’t love it but it came with the house when we bought it.

It now has a small sag next to one of the registers and I’m curious how to best fix it.  Should I drive a 3” screw up from the bottom and patch the crack and new screw?

The following pictures should hopefully illustrate the issue

[image: crack forming at duct opening]
[image: visible sag at crack site]

Comment: what kind of wood work is behind, why 3 inch screw ?

Comment: What kind of wood?  I’m actually not sure since I’ve never torn it open.  As for the screw?  Honestly, because I have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: use a magnet and try to find the screws from underneath, then take one out (it will be very small patch afterward), but you will know what is holding it up.

Comment: This is what oval is for and why metal studs suck. Step one is pulling the drywall. Do you really want to get into that?

Comment: Is there a floor register above it on the 2nd fl? That isn't installed so well and stepping on it did this? Or it feeds a chase up to the attic with no supports.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, sounds like the right thing to do is open it up.  Though, I may try to add a few more screws in the interim.  There is no floor register above, but that is a good thought as I can imagine pressure from above could affect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a sagiing of the soffit framing and not just the drywall. Perhaps your idea can work (or at least help a bit) but to actually correct the situation would require removal of the drywall and an inspection/ repair  of the underlying soffit framing.

Comment: Agreed, they are going to have to "open it up" to see what's going on. The framing is probably really inadequate (like you said).  The only way to fix this properly is to open it up and re-frame as needed.